# How to make VSCode's python debugger skip stepping into some modules when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode's python (ms-python) extension, is there a way to make the debugger (debugpy) not to step-into functions defined in specific modules. I have found *justMyCode* but it will skip entering into external modules only (like members of stdlib) while I need to skip my own modules sometimes.

I saw some debug adaptors for some other languages implement skipFiles property. Is there anything similar for python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going thru debugpy code I found this undocumented feature which works like a charm: in launch.json's debug configuration add
`"rules" : [{"module":"*xxx*", "include":false}]`. Make sure the *xxx* is the full module name like a.b.module

There are more working options. They can be seen [here](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/blob/fad8ae6577fcb14d762acac837000d5b758c00cd/src/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/tests_python/test_pydevd_filtering.py#L160)

A word of warning. This feature *is* undocumented (at least I did not find it anywhere) so use with caution as it might disappear one day. At the other hand, this feature **is** properly tested as part of the code uni-testing (as you can see from the link)